# AppEngine Gateway Timeout

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to write 25,200 entries to my appengine (in go). My appengine account is "pcsotinoodcom".

What I did was upload a gzip text file having a JSON encoded arrays of size 25,200. Then decompress the file with the appengine and then write the entries to the datastore.

It seems that some entries got written and some weren't and I keep getting a "Gateway Timeout" error.

Why am I getting the "Gateway Timeout" error? And how can I insert 25,200 entries to the datastore?

Thanks,
AM

Comment: you doing this all in one request ? could it be that this request takes longer then 30 seconds ? if so that is your issue, to prevent this, just use a task queue for decompress and upload, or a background servie which dont have this 30 seconds limit

Comment: Yes, am doing this in one request. Thank you, am not aware with the 30 seconds limit, and it seems to be it.

Comment: let me know if it was this 30 sec limit

Comment: Use the remote api then it can run for as long as you want. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/uploadingdata#Setting_Up_remote_api

Comment: It was the request limit. I am using the taskqueue now :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine automatic scaling instances enforce a 60 second [time limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes) (deadline) on user-facing HTTP requests. This was [increased from 30 seconds](http://googleappengine.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/app-engine-155-sdk-release.html) back in 2011.

[Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) has a deadline of 10 minutes, so this is a good choice for long-running operations.

[Manual and basic scaling instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes) also allow much longer deadlines (24 hours) but very long-running requests may fail occasionally due to transient issues or upgrades. Splitting the operation into chunks means there's less work to re-do in the event of a transient failure.